# Ansible regex_replace does not work

Tags: regex, ansible, configuration-management

```
"{{ archive_name | regex_replace('^(.*-)?.*-(.*)-.*-.*-.*-.*', '\\g<1>')}}"
```

Command above gives me an error in Ansible. `archive_name` is in the format of `alpine-1.10-324bghz-i-2018-0503`. I'm trying to grab the version number `1.10`. It returns an error with `\\g<1>\` instead of the version number. Am I doing something wrong? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No sure but if `\\g<1>` points to the first capturing group then you might use the second capturing group as that is what the regex matches for your string [`^(.*-)?.*-(.*)-.*-.*-.*-.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lHyaSy/1). Your first capturing group is optional. Or update the regex to [`^.*-(.*)-.*-.*-.*-.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lHyaSy/2)

Comment: No luck unfortunately, the output: \"hub.docker.com/centos:\\g<1>\"

Comment: Did you try using [\\1](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#examples) instead of `\\g<1>`?

Comment: Yes I did, I get the following: \"hub.docker.com/alpine:\\1\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply split the string, avoiding regex altogether.

```
{{ archive_name.split('-')[1:2] | join('-') }}
```

In theory the result should return only `1.10` (unable to test).

Comment: Thank you sir! There's a special place in heaven for you!